# I want to stop the second request that is sent by the iron-ajax even before the first request sent is completed

Tags: polymer, polymer-3.x, iron-ajax

I have an api that takes 4 mins(approx.) to get completed in my polymer application. When I send the request at exact 2mins another request gets sent even after timeout and debounce-duration is set to 10 mins. I want to stop that second request sent or wait for the first request to get completed. Some suggested me to use fetch instead of iron-ajax. I need a fix in iron-ajax itself. Can I have a solution for this.

code goes here

```
<iron-ajax id="request"
       url={{request}}
       verbose
       handle-as="json"
       method="{{method}}"
       body="{{body}}"
       params="{{requestParams}}"
       on-error="onError"
       loading="{{loading}}"
       timeout=600000
       content-type="application/json"
       debounce-duration=600000
       last-error="{{lastError}}"
       last-response="{{lastResponse}}">
```

I hope this will get resolved. Thanks in advance

Comment: You may want to use Fetch API which is provided by all browsers nativly: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: @PascalL. I tried fetch also but I got the same response from that too. it holds good  if whatever the time you fix for is less than 2 mins.

Comment: debounce-duration can be set only for the requests that are sent automatically.

Comment: timeout happens at the time you you set but even before to that a new request will be sent to the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a Boolean variable in order to able call `this.$.request.generateRequest()` something like:

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-cemane)

```
static get properties() {return {
    _isRequest: {
         type: Boolean,
         value: true}}}

static get observers(){ return ['_checkLastResponse(lastResponse)'] }

__checkLastResponse(r) {
        // we have received a response from iron-ajax so allow for next call
        if (r) this._isRequest = true;}

// As you provided above code, you call ajax manually. 
_ajax_call() {
      if (this._isRequest) {
              this.$.request.generateRequest();
              this._isRequest = false; }
}

static get template() { return `
   <paper-button disabled="[[!_isReruest]]" on-tap="ajax_call">AJAX CALL</paper-button>
   .......
   `;}
```

So, you may remove the unnecessary properties something like `debounce-duration=600000`  etc.

Comment: HakanC.Thanks for the solution. Yes `debounce-duration` is not at all necessary in this scene, as it will be good to use only if the request is sent **automatically** and not **manually**. I will try as you suggested and let you know the outcome.